# Image texture in SCNMaterial is always grey. How to apply color?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I am writing an image recognition app by following this example from Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/detecting_images_in_an_ar_experience

Everything works fine so far, now i'd like to change the transparent plane overlay to an image. I set the material of the plane like this.

```
let image = "overlay"
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true;
material.isDoubleSided = false
material.diffuse.contents = image
material.ambient.contents = UIColor.white

let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
planeNode.geometry?.materials = [material]
```

The image is loaded and rendered, only that it is always lacking the color. Original image is red, the overlay is b/w.
I already tried many different settings for ambient and diffuse without success. What am i missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, here is what i found out:
Images shall not have the same name, even when saved in different groups or folders. I was using the name of the image as reference to load an overlay. When i changed the name and got the reference manually (by switch/case) everything works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

In your code the following line is a `String` type, not `UIImage` type:

```
let image: String = "overlay"
```

Try the following code:

```
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 10, height: 10)

let image = UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/texture")
// let image = UIColor.red
// let image = UIColor(hue: 0.25, saturation: 0.5, brightness: 0.75, alpha: 1)

let material = SCNMaterial()
material.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true
material.isDoubleSided = false
material.diffuse.contents = image
material.ambient.contents = UIColor.white

let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
planeNode.geometry?.materials = [material]

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

Also, save your image for `diffuse` material slot as `PNG` format.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately it does not make a difference. According to Apples documentation here (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents) the content property also takes NSStrings with the images location, same as UIImage, UIColor and other. 

However, i observed an odd behaviour. When i hardcode the image location into the code, it works fine. If I build the location from i.e. the referenceImages name property, i get the same old problem.